# How can I create a Memory<T> from a Span<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to overload a parsing method to use a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` parameter in addition to the `string` version. The problem is that the implementation uses a `Dictionary<string, T>` for the parsing logic.

I tried switching it to a `Dictionary<ReadOnlySpan<char>, T>` but of course that didn't work as `ReadOnlySpan<char>` isn't allowed as a generic parameter since it's a stack only object. I then switched it to using `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` which is allowed. I then implemented a basic `Ordinal` comparer but am now having troubles creating a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` from the `ReadOnlySpan<char>` parameter. Is this possible?

**Update**

It seems that this is not possible. In order to support the scenario I've posted above I will change the dictionary to have an int key which is the hashcode of the `ReadOnlySpan<char>` and make the value a list with the string embedded in the element and manually have to resolve hash code collisions.

Comment: There should be an `AsMemory()` method in `System.MemoryExtensions` class to do this, can’t test since on mobile

Comment: Unfortunately, `AsMemory()` only accepts `string`s, arrays, and `ArraySegment<T>`s.

Comment: As Spans live on stack you have to copy it to the heap using ToArray() method. Arrays are implicitly converted to ReadOnlyMemory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### TL;DR:

You can go `Memory<T>` to `Span<T>`, but not the other way around.

### Background:

There is an informative 2018 MSDN Magazine article article that introduces `Span<T>` in a 2018 [MSDN Magazine article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/january/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay)

> `Span<T>` instances can only live on the stack, not on the heap. **This means you can’t box spans** (and thus can’t use `Span<T>` with existing reflection invoke APIs, for example, as they require boxing). It means you can’t have `Span<T>` fields in classes, or even in non-ref-like structs. It means you can’t use spans in places where they might implicitly become fields on classes, for instance by capturing them into lambdas or as locals in async methods or iterators (as those “locals” may end up being fields on the compiler-generated state machines.) It also means you can’t use `Span<T>` as a generic argument, as instances of that type argument could end up getting boxed or otherwise stored to the heap (and there’s currently no “`where T : ref struct`” constraint available).
>
> ...
>
> You can create a `Memory<T>` from an array and slice it just as you
> would a span, but it’s a (non-ref-like) struct and can live on the
> heap. Then, when you want to do synchronous processing, you can get a
> `Span<T>` from it, for example:
>
> ```
> static async Task<int> ChecksumReadAsync(Memory<byte> buffer, Stream stream)
> {
>   int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
>   return Checksum(buffer.Span.Slice(0, bytesRead));
>   // Or buffer.Slice(0, bytesRead).Span
> }
> static int Checksum(Span<byte> buffer) { ... }
> ```

I think his article clears it up better than me writing my own answer.

Comment: Put the short words at the front for saving others times please.

Comment: It's curious how `Memory<T>` has the `public Span<T> Span { get; }` property, but doesn't have an `implicit operator Span<T>( Memory<T> self )` operator unlike we see with `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can go from a `Span<T>` to a `Memory<T>` if `T` is an [unmanaged type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types). But beware that the `Memory<T>` object you are creating should enforce "manually" all the constraints that C# compiler guarantees on Spans.

```cs
// data is Span<T> or ReadOnlySpan<T>
fixed (T* pointer = &data.GetPinnableReference())
{
     using var memoryManager = new UnmanagedMemoryManager<T>(pointer, data.Length);
     var memory = memoryManager.Memory;
     // you must use the memory object inside this fixed block!
}
```

The `UnmanagedMemoryManager` can be found in the nuget package `Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial` (I don't maintain this package). But you can also code [your own implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorymanager-1?view=net-5.0) of an unmanaged `MemoryManager<T>` if you prefer to build it differently.